# CORS Error when Integrating React, Flask, and Google OAuth

Tags: reactjs, flask, oauth, cors, google-oauth

I'm building a web application that combines a React frontend and a Flask backend. I'm using Google OAuth for authentication. Here's a simplified overview of my setup:

Here's my react code snippet:

```
  const handleGoogleSignIn = () =>{
    const url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/Oauth/Login"
    axios.post(url,{headers:"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("success")
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        setErrorMessage("Invalid login or password");
      });
  }
```

Here's my Flask code snippet:

```
# Oauth2Params configuration
app.secret_key = 'random secret'
oauth = OAuth(app)
oauth.register(
    name='google',
    client_id=google_client_id,
    client_secret=google_client_secret,
    authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid profile email', 'prompt': 'select_account'},
)

# Flask route
@app.route('/Oauth/Login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def OuathLogin():
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True)
    return oauth.google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)
```

I was expecting that flask will redirect me to google login page but,
Here's the problem:

The React app sends an OPTIONS request from http://127.0.0.1:3000, which receives a 200 OK response from the Flask server.
Then, it sends a POST request to /Oauth/Login, which gets a 302 redirection to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth.
However, at this point, I'm encountering the following CORS error:

[Networking on devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVo4x.png)
[console cors on devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SfAw.png)

Thank you for you help